# Override class variable/method on inherited classes

Tags: java

I've defined a class, and I'd like to have a class method (or variable, I don't really care) which needs to be overriden by each inherited class. My best approaches have been unsuccessful:

`public abstract String getHumanString();`, as abstract methods can't be static

`public static String getHumanString();`, as static methods can only be hidden, not overriden.

I don't know if there is another trick I could use. I could also be happy to automatically define `getHumanString()` by myself on the parent class with something like humanize(`class.getClass().getName()`) (I'd just make `getName()` look more beautiful, according to my needs), `getName()` is not accessible on static methods. So, to sum up, my question is:

**1. Can I have a static method/variable which could be edited on subclasses?**

OR, as another valid solution:

**2. Can I create a static method that plays with its own class name?**

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Imagine this situation (I'll skip useless lines, as I'm directly writing code here):

```
class ParentClass {
    public static (or whatever) String getHumanString() {
        return "My Parent Class";
    }

    public static showMyInfo() {
        System.out.println(getHumanString());
    }
}

class ChildClass {
    @Override
    public static (or whatever) String getHumanString() {
        return "My Child Class";
    }
}
```

...

```
public static void main()
{
   ChildClass.showMyInfo();
}
```

It should output (as I'd want) "My Child Class", but it actually outputs (as you all know) "My Parent Class".

Comment: static methods are always resolved at compile time. It doesn't make much sense to want them overridable. You should explain us what you want to do, at a higher level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to have a readable name for each class (not just getClass().getName()), which does not depend on the object instance. In fact, I'd like to avoid instancing that class when I need getHumanString().

Have a properties file, with class name as key and human string as value. And a single static method somewhere to read it.

```
 static String getHumanString(Class<?> clazz){
     return humanStrings.getProperty(clazz.getName(), clazz.getSimpleName());
 }
```

Also lends itself to localization if necessary. Plus you can "enhance" existing classes whose definition you cannot change.

Comment: Yours is a fresh idea I didn't consider before, so I think I'd go for this one! Also +1 for localization

Answer (score 4):

Static methods aren't polymorphic, no. Nor are variables, by the way - you can't override variables, even instance ones. You can hide them, but not override them.

It's not really clear what you're trying to do, to be honest - but you may want to *consider* a corresponding type hierarchy so that the static methods become instance methods in the new types.

Comment: +1. Even if you could enforce that all subclasses implement a certain static method (which you cannot), there is not much of a point, because they don't override anything so there is no dynamic dispatch. Those methods would only be called if the caller explicitly asked for them (by concrete class name).

Comment: That, or consider using an interface. Do you need to use static methods/fields at all?

Comment: I'd like to have a readable name for each class (not just `getClass().getName()`), which does not depend on the object instance. In fact, I'd like to avoid instancing that class when I need `getHumanString()`.

Comment: @Kor: No, a call to a static method `SubClass.foo()` where `foo()` is actually declared in `SuperClass` basically gets converted into a call to `SuperClass.foo()` by the compiler, so there's no way of telling them apart. Where are you using this? Maybe there are alternative approaches from a higher level.

Comment: Then just add a constant of static method on each class. Hiding is what you want here.

Comment: @Jon Skeet yes, I knew about that, I just was waiting for a miracle.

Comment: @JB Nizet hiding needs the class to be instanced (which converts it to a non-static method, so abstract methods are better fitted here), something I'm trying to escape from :(

Comment: No. If a static method of a subclass has the same signature as a static method of it superclass, it's said to hide the superclass method. You call the methods using Subclass.someMethod() and SuperClass.someMethod().

Answer (score 0):

If this is a requirement I would suggest splitting the `static` members and fields into a class(es) of their own.  This way your existing class can refer to a single `static` instance of a class which is polymorphic.